# Check if list item field has a specific value

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, development, csom, event-receivers

I have a custom list in SharePoint (List A) with a choice column (1,2,3).

I have created three items in this list --> item 1, item 2, item 3.

I want to check the value of these items (for the choice column) to get all items that have the value of 2.

Anyone that can help me with this? I prefer to do it in an event receiver if this is possible...

Answer (score 1):

**First,** You should use the `CAML Query` to retrive the desired items based on a specifc critiria (`Choice Field = 2`) as the following:

```
SPQuery Qry = new SPQuery();
Qry.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="choice column name" /><Value Type="Choice">2</Value></Eq></Where>";
Qry.RowLimit = 100;
```

> **Note:** You can use U2U tool to build your CAML Query based on your
>   requirements, to download the tool check [U2U tool](https://www.u2u.be/software)

**Secondly,** you can get all items from a specific list based on your CAML query as the following:

```
SPList List = myWeb.Lists["ListName"];
SPListItemCollection Items = List.GetItems(Qry);
```

**Finally,** Loop for the retrieved items filtered by choice field = 2

```
foreach (SPListItem Item in Items)
{
 // do something
}
```

---

**The final code should look like (Not Test)**

```
    SPWeb  Web = properties.OpenWeb();
    SPQuery Qry = new SPQuery();
    Qry.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="choice column name" /><Value Type="Choice">2</Value></Eq></Where>";
    Qry.RowLimit = 100;
    SPList List = web.Lists["ListName"];
    SPListItemCollection Items = List.GetItems(Qry);
    foreach (SPListItem Item in Items)
    {
     // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve it via JavaScript.

Here is a demo for your reference.

```
    var siteUrl = 'http://sp/sites/DevSite';
    var clientContext;
    var collListItem;
    var collListItems;

    $(function () {

        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var camlString = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="choice column name" /><Value Type="Choice">2</Value></Eq></Where>';
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlString);
        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getAllListItemSucceeded, getAllListItemFailed);
     });

    function getAllListItemSucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        $("#tbody").empty();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            //do something
        }
    }
```